# How do you create a transaction that spans multiple statements in Python with MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql

I know that with an InnoDB table, transactions are autocommit, however I understand that to mean for a single statement? For example, I want to check if a user exists in a table, and then if it doesn't, create it. However there lies a race condition. I believe using a transaction prior to doing the select, will ensure that the table remains untouched until the subsequent insert, and the transaction is committed. How can you do this with MySQLdb and Python?

Answer (score 4):

There exists a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE that allows you to lock the rows from being read by another transaction but I believe the records have to exist in the first place. Then you can do as you say, and unlock it once you commit.

In your case I think the best approach is to simply set a unique constraint on the username and try to insert. If you get a key exception you can notify the user that the name was already taken.

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @JoshN yes that's what I'm talking about. Thank you for posting the link.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you could [disable auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617637/pythons-mysqldb-not-getting-updated-row/1617662#1617662), the do a [Two Phase Commit transaction](http://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2008/03/04/python-tpc/), as defined in [Python's DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). It seems a bit harder to come by that feature in the wild. SQLAlchemy [seems to include support](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#enabling-two-phase-commit) for it on MySQL, so it is possible.