# python mysqldb insert data evaporating without error

Tags: python, mysql

first post; i've been helped many times by others' questions but now i'm completely stuck.

i am working in python, using MySQLdb (imported as 'mysql' below) and am trying to do an insert. this code, isolated with its own connection for debugging, immediately follows a completely successful insert to a different table in the same database using (previous to debugging) the same connection.

```
  import MySQLdb as mysql
  from futuremachine import data

  j = {};

  return_id = 7201;
  j['boxids'] = [u'28']

  ...

  local_connection = data.environment('development');
  local_db = mysql.connect(**local_connection);
  local_curs = local_db.cursor();
  if local_db.autocommit:
    print "AUTOCOMMIT ON";
  else:
    print "EUREKA";

  # insert the new set of labels
  for label_id in j['boxids']:
    query = """
    insert into eventlabels values (%s, %s)
    """
    args = [int(return_id),int(label_id)]

    try:
      #local_curs.execute(query,args);
      data.executive(local_curs,query,args);
      #local_db.commit()
    except mysql.Error, e:
      sys.exit("sql error:\n" + query + "\n%s" % e);

    ci = local_db.info()
    rc = local_db.affected_rows()
    print "info: "+str(ci);
    print "affected: "+str(rc);

  local_db.close();
```

the 'data.executive' is a wrapper to curs.execute; i have tried this with and without the wrapper to the same result. return_id is the lastrowid from the previous insert, which works every time; dummy values are given above.

the info() returns None; even more frustrating, affected_rows() returns 1.

the query produces no errors, yet when i check the table for the inserted data, it is not there.

1. autocommit is on; calling commit() directly has no effect
2. verified the connecting user has privileges to insert to the table
3. the query appears in the system mysql.log

this is all i can think to include at this time. all the answers i have found were solved by connection.commit(), which hasn't helped thus far.

the table in question:

```
mysql> show full columns from eventlabels;
+---------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field   | Type    | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+---------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| eventid | int(11) | NULL      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| labelid | int(11) | NULL      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+---------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

thank you for any light you may be able to shed on this.

Comment: please provide a small code snippet that clearly demonstrates this issue ... this code is not an MVC (it relies on variables that are not included in the code)

Comment: ok, i've specified the nature of the variables not explicitly specified; any thoughts? near as i can figure maybe the label_id being a unicode string it doesn't convert to int cleanly, except every way to debug this i can think of has made no indication this is an issue.

Comment: well, i'm not going to give out my database credentials, but i have added the lines as you requested. works locally here, except of course for the lack of inserted data. any thoughts?

--

not sure what happened to your previous reply @JoranBeasley, but as you requested this is code complete (minus login creds)

Comment: please duplicate your table somewhere you are willing to share (ie http://www.freesqldatabase.com/) ... or at the very least give us the schema commands to recreate your database ourselves ... without having to reverse engineer it from your print out ... I started working on this ... but at this point its going to take an hour just to get to where I can replicate your problem and I dont have that kind of time to spend on answering a question ...

Comment: could you please give the complete list of your requirements for assistance? this is your third request, and while i'd like help the excitement of seeing a comment immediately followed by the disappointment of seeing a further request for information is only adding to the frustration. if you can provide a complete list of what you need, i am happy to provide it.

Comment: the same thing ive been asking for since the first comment (ie **code that can be copied and pasted** and will demonstrate the issue) ... (often in the process of creating a small snip of code that readily demonstrates the issue and is complete(can be copied and pasted and ran), you will end up encountering what your actual problem was and the solution to it ..)

Comment: fine. i will go sign up for a free database service. meanwhile, i tried the exact same code on the production database (same schema, same hardware, etc) and got the same result. i will update again when the database is set. am i to intuit there is nothing visible in the code that suggests an issue?

Comment: naw it looks reasonable ... and lots and lots and lots of people use mysqldb without issue... which leads me to believe you really just need a `db.commit()` somewhere (I know you said you dont ... ) but really, to get help with anything more than a couple lines **you need to post a fully copy/pastable/runable code example** ) unless the error is really really obvious ... and your right, creating a second db just to demonstrate is a pain in the ass ... almost as big as trying to create a db without a schema provided, to help solve a problem for someone else :P

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer in two parts:

http://laviefrugale.blogspot.com/2011/03/python-and-mysql-autocommit.html

which then refers to this local answer:

[Python's MySqlDB not getting updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617637/pythons-mysqldb-not-getting-updated-row)

setting up a remote database didn't get me much of anywhere, but as it turns out the database in question is set up oddly:

```
mysql> select table_name,engine FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();
+-------------+--------+
| table_name  | engine |
+-------------+--------+
| eventlabels | InnoDB |
| events      | MyISAM |
| labels      | InnoDB |
+-------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

the inexplicable behavior referred to above was the result of the autocommit() setting working on the first insert (events, a very old MyISAM table), but then the setting is ignored by eventlabels because it's InnoDB.

what i can't quite figure out is why the manual commit made no difference, or testing db.autocommit produced a non-EUREKA result, but in the end, setting autocommit explicitly for the connection solved the problem.

```
local_db.autocommit(True);
```

in context:

```
local_connection = data.environment('development');
local_db = mysql.connect(**local_connection);
local_db.autocommit(True);
local_curs = local_db.cursor();
```

if you've read this far, here's hoping this helped you; meanwhile MyISAM, InnoDB, and yours truly lived happily ever after.

Comment: I knew you would solve the problem :P +5 if i could ... solving your own problem is always the best :)